# How do I make JSON accessible from inside of many arrays?

Tags: c#, json

I hope it doesn't seem like I want to be spoon-fed at this rate of asking questions, but this next question is a bit more difficult and I don't understand how to solve this at all.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": "5d914028302b840050acbe62",
      "picture": "https://utellyassets9-1.imgix.net/api/Images/4e4d50a0040fd4500193202edbafce6a/Redirect",
      "name": "BoJack Horseman",
      "locations": [
        {
          "icon": "https://utellyassets7.imgix.net/locations_icons/utelly/black_new/NetflixIVAUS.png?w=92&auto=compress&app_version=ae3576e2-0796-4eda-b953-80cadc8e2619_eww2020-05-08",
          "display_name": "Netflix",
          "name": "NetflixIVAUS",
          "id": "5d81fe2fd51bef0f42268f0f",
          "url": "https://www.netflix.com/title/70298933"
        }
      ],
      "provider": "iva",
      "weight": 5654,
      "external_ids": {
        "iva_rating": null,
        "imdb": {
          "url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3398228",
          "id": "tt3398228"
        },
        "tmdb": {
          "url": "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/61222",
          "id": "61222"
        },
        "wiki_data": {
          "url": "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q17733404",
          "id": "Q17733404"
        },
        "iva": {
          "id": "783721"
        },
        "gracenote": null,
        "rotten_tomatoes": null,
        "facebook": null
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "5e2ce07890c0e033a487e3d2",
      "picture": "https://utellyassets9-1.imgix.net/api/Images/326d2853ff6885c41b9adb05278017f6/Redirect",
      "name": "Dragon Ball Z: Bojack Unbound",
      "locations": [
        {
          "icon": "https://utellyassets7.imgix.net/locations_icons/utelly/black_new/iTunesIVAUS.png?w=92&auto=compress&app_version=ae3576e2-0796-4eda-b953-80cadc8e2619_eww2020-05-08",
          "display_name": "iTunes",
          "name": "iTunesIVAUS",
          "id": "5d80a9a5d51bef861d3740d3",
          "url": "https://itunes.apple.com/us/movie/dragon-ball-z-bojack-unbound-subtitled-original-version/id1381102560"
        }
      ],
      "provider": "iva",
      "weight": 0,
      "external_ids": {
        "iva_rating": null,
        "imdb": {
          "url": "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0142238",
          "id": "tt0142238"
        },
        "tmdb": {
          "url": "https://www.themoviedb.org/movie/39105",
          "id": "39105"
        },
        "wiki_data": {
          "url": "https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1255010",
          "id": "Q1255010"
        },
        "iva": {
          "id": "406043"
        },
        "gracenote": null,
        "rotten_tomatoes": null,
        "facebook": null
      }
    }
  ],
  "updated": "2020-05-08T05:19:01+0100",
  "term": "Bojack",
  "status_code": 200,
  "variant": "ivafull"
}
```

Alright, so the `first 0:` represents the option that the API returned (so in this case it's bojack horseman) and any following number (if it said `1: afterward`) would be a different result.

I tried writing a second class to deal with results (`resultoverall`) that is controlled by the overall,

```
    public class overall
    {
        [JsonProperty("status_code")]
        public string status_code { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("term")]
        public string term { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("updated")]
        public string updated { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("results")]
        public List<resultoverall> results { get; set; }


    }

    public partial class resultoverall
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }


    }
```

and tried

```
overall BestGamer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<overall>(thicky);
List<overall> ObjOrderList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<overall>>(thicky);
```

to be able to access data from both outside of the `0:` and inside of the `0:` (BestGamer / overall handles outside, resultoverall / Tapioca handles inside, but I get error about the type requiring a JSON array
even though it is already in an array format.

How do I set this up to access data inside of the `0:`, for *each* number that appears (so if there is 2 options I can access info from both?

Using `Console.WriteLine(BestGamer.updated);` correctly gives me the info from the overall group, but using the `Console.WriteLine(BestGamer.results.name);` does not work, saying:

> Error CS1061  'extension method 'name' accepting a first argument of type 'List<resultoverall>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: The json is corrupt and malformed. I suggest you check it and correct it

Comment: Fixed :) @MichaelRandall

Answer (score 0):

You have a JSON object, not an array. Therefore you can't deserialize it as an array. That is correct. You are already deserializing it to an object. So after

```
overall BestGamer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<overall>(thicky);
```

You can access the objects in `results` like

```
var numberOfResults = BestGamer.results.Count;
var firstResult = BestGamer.results[0];
var firstResultsName = BestGamer.results[0].name;
// or loop through the results
foreach (var item in BestGamer.results)
{
    // item.Name gives you the name of the current result
}
```